# Unable to use Robo3t

Tags: command-line, mongodb

I'm trying to use robo3t on Ubuntu WSL but I'm getting this error while running `robo3t` command, and find nothing about it

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Comment: WSL in command-line only. You don't have a graphic desktop.

Comment: So i can't use robo3t on WSL ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install an X server and than ssh to your machine using the `-X` flag in order to enable te X11 forwarding